# Angular 2 - Add Value of Checked Radio Button to Array

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get the checked radio button and add the value to an Array. Currently, i cannot remove the previously checked radio buttons, so basically it keeps adding to the array every time i select a radio button.

**item.component.ts**

```
displaySelectedConditions(event) { 
  if(event.target.checked) {
  this.selectedConditionsArr.push(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

**item.component.html**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | funder "> //generates 4 items
     <a><input type="radio" (change) = "displaySelectedConditions($event);" 
               name="funder" id="{{item}}" value="{{item}}">
     <label for="{{item}}" >{{item}}</label></a>
   </li>
</ul><!-- Dropdown Menu -->
```

Comment: Plunker would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you use an array? Since only one radio button is checked at any time, couldn't you keep only the newly selected value?

Comment: Yes i could have, but i have 3 more radio groups. So i thought, Array would be clean way to keep them. check it on plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/DCxaGkQFNs3cUDHnp6yG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest if you want to have the values neatly stored somewhere, then make use of a form. Simple template driven form works well here, then you would have all your values stored in an object, here's a sample:

```html
<form #radioGroup="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let str of strings">
    <input type="radio" [value]="str" name="str" ngModel />{{str}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div *ngFor="let num of numbers">
    <input type="radio" [value]="num" name="num" ngModel />{{num}}
  </div>
</form>
```

This would create an object like:

```ts
{
  str: "value here",
  num: "value here"
}
```

And if you declare the form like the following, you can easily access the object values:

```ts
@ViewChild('radioGroup') radioGroup: NgForm;
```

Somewhere in component:

```ts
console.log(this.radioGroup.value);
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UtZaiYkRwL1mIW1SnXAR?p=preview)**